# Wordpress: Jquery works inline, NOT on an external file

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

my problem is quite annoying and weird. I have created a custom Wordpress theme and in the header.php I was loading jquery like this (can't remember why right now):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> google.load("jquery", "1"); </script>
```

Last night I replaced the code above with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then my site collapsed. I changed it immediately back again, but the problem persisted. I placed some Jquery in the HTML and it works just fine. Then I disabled my plugins by commenting out code in my functions.php file as below:

```
<?php

if (!is_admin()) {

wp_register_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js');
wp_enqueue_script('custom');

wp_register_script('blockui',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.blockUI.js');
wp_enqueue_script('blockui');

wp_register_script('fancy',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.fancybox.js');
wp_enqueue_script('fancy');

wp_register_script('jeasing',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.easing.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jeasing');

wp_register_script('friendchooser',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.friendChooser.js');
wp_enqueue_script('friendchooser');

wp_register_script('zclip', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.zclip.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('zclip');
}
?>
```

Still the problem occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem? Any errors in js console?

Comment: Sorry! everything seems to be inactive...for example in my custom.js I have code like this jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 $('h1').hide();
 
 $('#btn_clipboard').zclip({
 path:'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
 copy:function(){return $('#clipboard_text').val();}
 }); 
 
});  and this does not get fired

Comment: Without any errors/notifications in js console? Check it with firebug.

Comment: Am not very familiar with firebug (not a web dev), but I shall try now, my testing site is http://kokas.x10.mx/?page_id=2 by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error in custom.js file in line 30. Just remove `}` from there.

And learn some about firebug, it's very helpful :)

Comment: falling in love with it now!